# JQuery Scoping Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call an external script with JQuery. I would usually use something like this:

```
<script src="../DashboardRecreationScripts/basicModel.js"></script>
```

However, I am already inside a script tag which includes a document.ready function so I can't make the call outside either.

This is the problem I am having:

I have made  a call to an external file using this:

```
$.getScript("../DashboardRecreationScripts/basicModel.js").done(function (script, textStatus) {
       alert(textStatus);
})
```

Inside the external file I have a backbone js model. This works fine.
However, nothing below the '$.getScript()' has access to that model. Even though they are all wrapped in a document ready function.

Thanks

Comment: That's because `$.getScript` is asynchronous

Comment: Okay, thank you. Do you have any recommendations for a work around?

Comment: $.getScript is asynchronous, if you want to work with the result, you ought to do it in the .done callback function. What do you have in your script variable ?

Comment: Oh right I see thank you. And the script variable contains the code in the external file. (The backbone.js model)